# SQL Server query times out after changing nvarchar 3000 to nvarchar 4000

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a table in a production database in which I changed one of the column lengths from `Nvarchar(3000)` to `Nvarchar(4000)`.

After that the application team is getting a timeout error. Could any of you suggest how to troubleshoot this issue?

There were no blockings when the query was executed.

Comment: Did you rebuild all indexes pointing to that column?

Comment: No I dint rebuild the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times, timeouts relate to statistics not being up to date...

Try rebuilding indexes. Since you have changed a column, it might cause some fragmentation.

```
ALTER INDEX all ON yourtable REBUILD
```

And try updating statistics as well, since an index rebuild updates only indexed column statistics.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS yourtable WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS
```

If you are still getting timeouts, try to fine-tune the queries involved.

Answer (score 0):

After such change data could be heavilly distributed over storage and this could cause enormously high i/o. Rebulding indexes/statistics is for sure worth to try but please also consider creating new table and move data to this newly created table.

To check if I/O is high please use SET STATISTICS IO ON.

Of course it would be perfect if you could compare it with old version.